# Greasemonkey script on Firefox network error page

Tags: firefox, greasemonkey

I want to run a Greasemonkey script on Firefox network error pages, such as (but not limited to) this one:

[image]

Can I do this with `chrome://` URLs?  If so, what are they?  If not, is there another way?

Comment: Do you have a page or server that reliably generates connection resets?  (To test workarounds)

Comment: @Brock No, I don't, and if it comes down to heavy testing then it's easier just to ditch my silly little script.  Well, I shouldn't say that because right now woot.com is giving me _tons_ of connection resets :)

Comment: I don't think GM will fire on chrome pages, but need to gin up a way to test this.  Try a simple script with the directive, `// @include *` and see if it fires.  A custom FF add-on/extension should be able to work on such pages, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I was almost on the right track.  Two things:

1. Network error pages begin with `about:neterror`, not `chrome://`.  If you try to access `ww.example.com` (missing a w) then you will be redirected to `about:neterror?e=dnsNotFound&u=http%3A//ww.example.com/&c=UTF-8&d=Firefox%20can%27t%20find%20the%20server%20at%20ww.example.com`
2. You cannot `// @include about:neterror*`.

But since we know the URL format, we can

```
// @include *
```

and check:

```
if (document.documentURI.search('about:neterror') != -1) {
    doStuffOnNetError();
}
```

Thanks for the hints, Brock.

Comment: You're welcome and pretty nifty workaround.   verified that it does work on the *The connection was reset* condition, too. +1